# Update taxonomy terms when changing language in node form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy with different terms for each language. If I create a new node, the terms for English are loaded; if I change language on the node to German, I would like to update the taxonomy list with German terms.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_node_update($node) {
  // Check for the language and do your stuff.
}
```